# User defined URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link button in an application

```
  = link_to "Hello" , :controller => "pages" , :action => "home"
```

On a click of this link the generated url is "localhost:3000/pages/home". But i want, the url should be displayed like=> "localhost:3000/hello" Is there any way in rails to do this?

Comment: To see all available pathes just run 'rake routes'

Answer (score 3):

You could set up a [named route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes):

```
match 'hello' => 'pages#home', :as => :hello
```

In your view:

```
= link_to "Hello", hello_path
```

Comment: Can i define it as match :controller => :pages, :action => :home, :as => :hello

Comment: `'pages#home'` is a shortcut for `:controller => :pages, :action => :home`, you can write it either way.

Comment: I m getting following Error: undefined local variable or method `hello_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x2aee651a5530>)

Comment: Maybe the path is [nested](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)/[namespaced](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) or you haven't specified `:as => :hello`. Run [`rake routes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#seeing-existing-routes-with-rake) to get a list of available routes, the first entry in each line is the route's name.

Answer (score 0):

you can name URL as you want, and can mapped in routes.rb. In your case you can use `match`
Here is the example:

```
in your route.rb
match 'hello' => 'pages#home', :as => :hello
```

Now in `link_to "hello", home_path`
You can find more options in [documentaion](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this

```
resources :pages do
  collection do
    get :hello
  end
end
```